# Зачем нужно использовать графическую сцену QGraphicsScene?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview

Объясните простыми словами зачем стоит использовать графическую сцену?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не простая, но очень важная тема и простых слов тут будет недостаточно.

Класс [**QGraphicsScene**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) предоставляет поверхность для управления большим количеством 2D-графических элементов.

Класс служит контейнером для `QGraphicsItems`.
Он используется вместе с `QGraphicsView` для визуализации графических элементов,
таких как линии, прямоугольники, текст или даже пользовательские элементы, на 2D-поверхности. 
**`QGraphicsScene`** является частью `Graphics View Framework`.

[**Graphics View Framework**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html)
`Graphics View` (Графическое представление) предоставляет поверхность для управления и взаимодействия с большим количеством настраиваемых 2D-графических элементов, а также виджет представления для визуализации элементов с поддержкой масштабирования и поворота.

Платформа включает в себя архитектуру распространения событий,
которая обеспечивает точные возможности взаимодействия с двойной точностью для элементов на сцене. 
Элементы могут обрабатывать ключевые события, нажатие мыши, перемещение, отпускание и двойной щелчок, а также могут отслеживать движение мыши.

Графический вид использует дерево BSP (Binary Space Partitioning),
чтобы обеспечить очень быстрое обнаружение элементов,
и в результате этого он может визуализировать большие сцены в реальном времени,
даже с миллионами элементов.

**`Архитектура графического представления`**

`Graphics View` обеспечивает основанный на элементах подход к программированию модели-представления, очень похожий на удобные классы InterView QTableView, QTreeView и QListView. 
Несколько представлений могут наблюдать за одной сценой,
а сцена содержит элементы различной геометрической формы.

**`Scene`**

**`QGraphicsScene`** предоставляет сцену графического представления. Сцена имеет следующие обязанности:

- Предоставление быстрого интерфейса для управления большим количеством элементов
- Распространение событий на каждый элемент
- Управление состоянием элемента, например выбор и обработка фокуса
- Предоставление непреобразованной функциональности рендеринга

**`Сцена служит контейнером для объектов QGraphicsItem`**. 
Элементы добавляются на сцену с помощью вызова `QGraphicsScene::addItem()`,
а затем извлекаются с помощью вызова одной из многих функций обнаружения элементов. 
`QGraphicsScene::items()` и его перегруженные версии возвращают все элементы,
содержащиеся или пересекающиеся с точкой, прямоугольником, многоугольником
или общим векторным путем. 
`QGraphicsScene::itemAt()` возвращает самый верхний элемент в определенной точке. 
**`Все`** функции обнаружения элементов возвращают элементы в порядке убывания
(т. е. первый возвращенный элемент является самым верхним, а последний — самым нижним).

Архитектура распространения событий **`QGraphicsScene`** планирует доставку событий сцены к элементам, а также управляет распространением между элементами.
Если сцена получает событие нажатия мыши в определенной позиции,
сцена передает событие любому элементу, находящемуся в этой позиции.

**`QGraphicsScene`** также управляет некоторыми состояниями элементов, такими как **`выбор элемента и фокус`**. 
Вы можете выбирать элементы на сцене, вызывая `QGraphicsScene::setSelectionArea()`, передавая произвольную форму.
Эта функциональность также используется в качестве основы для выделения резинкой в ​​`QGraphicsView`. 
Чтобы получить список всех выбранных элементов, вызовите `QGraphicsScene::selectedItems()`. 
Еще одно состояние, обрабатываемое **`QGraphicsScene`**, — имеет ли элемент фокус ввода с клавиатуры.
Вы можете установить фокус на элементе, вызвав `QGraphicsScene::setFocusItem()`
или `QGraphicsItem::setFocus()`, или получить текущий элемент фокуса, вызвав `QGraphicsScene::focusItem()`.

Наконец, **`QGraphicsScene`** позволяет отображать части сцены в устройство рисования
с помощью функции [**QGraphicsScene::render()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#render).

---

**Framework графического представления**

Обычно `QLabel` используется для отображения изображений.
Но что, если вы хотите использовать много картинок?

Вы хотите создать множество элементов управления QLabel, чтобы отображать их один за другим? Как это сделать?

Мы не можем использовать элементы управления `QLabel` для таких действий,
это будет очень хлопотно и запутанно.

Графическое представление в *PyQt5* позволяет нам управлять и взаимодействовать с большим количеством пользовательских 2D-примитивов.

Каркас использует дерево `BSP` (Binary Space Partitioning) для быстрого поиска графических элементов.
Таким образом, даже если сцена просмотра содержит миллионы примитивов,
она может отображаться в режиме реального времени.

Если вы хотите использовать PyQt5 для создания немного более сложной игры,
необходимо использовать графическое представление.

**`Каркас графического представления в основном содержит три класса`**:

- примитивный класс `QGraphicsItem`,
- класс сцены **`QGraphicsScene`** и
- класс представления `QGraphicsView`.

Итог взаимосвязи между следующими тремя классами:           
**примитивы размещаются на сцене, а содержимое сцены отображается через представления.**

**`QGraphicsScene`**

Сцена предоставляет следующие методы, позволяющие нам быстро добавлять примитивы:

- Создает и добавляет элемент эллипса к сцене и возвращает указатель элемента.
- Создает и добавляет элемент Line в сцену и возвращает указатель элемента.
- Создает и добавляет элемент Path к сцене и возвращает указатель элемента.
- Создает и добавляет элемент растрового изображения в сцену и возвращает указатель элемента.
- Создает и добавляет элемент Polygon на сцену и возвращает указатель элемента.
- Создает и добавляет элемент прямоугольника к сцене и возвращает указатель элемента.
- Создает и добавляет QGraphicsSimpleTextItem к сцене и возвращает указатель элемента.
- Создает новый QGraphicsProxyWidget для виджета, добавляет его в сцену и
  возвращает указатель на прокси.

...

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform, QBrush, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView


class Demo(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        self.resize(300, 300)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 300, 300)

# 1 Вызовите методы addRect(), addEllipse() и addPixmap() сцены напрямую, чтобы добавить примитивы.
#   Вам нужно знать один момент здесь:
#   Элемент, который добавляется первым, находится ниже элемента, который добавляется позже 
#   (направление оси Z). Вы можете запустить код самостоятельно, а затем переместить элемент. 
#   После этого вы увидите, что элемент изображения в программе находится сверху, 
#   затем эллипс, а прямоугольник - в Внизу. 
#   Однако мы можем изменить верхнюю и нижнюю позиции, вызвав метод setZValue() примитива 
#   (пожалуйста, обратитесь к документации, чтобы понять, здесь подробно не объясняется).
#   QGraphicsItem::setZValue(qreal z)
        self.rect    = self.scene.addRect(100, 30, 100, 30, brush=QBrush(QColor(230, 30, 230)))
        self.ellipse = self.scene.addEllipse(100, 80, 50, 40, 
                                             brush=QBrush(QColor(230, 30, 30), Qt.Dense6Pattern))
        self.pic     = self.scene.addPixmap(QPixmap('ball.png').scaled(60, 60))
        self.pic.setOffset(100, 130) # установить смещение изображения от начала координат сцены;
        # По умолчанию Z-значение равно 0.
        # self.ellipse.setZValue(1)

#   Затем установите свойство Flag примитива. Дополнительный ItemIsFocusable здесь указывает,
#   что графика может быть сфокусирована (значение по умолчанию не фокусируется) .
#   Этот атрибут связан с сигналом focusItemChanged, описанным в третьем пункте ниже;
        self.rect.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | 
                           QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | 
                           QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)
        self.ellipse.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | 
                              QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | 
                              QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)
        self.pic.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | 
                          QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | 
                          QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)

        self.setScene(self.scene)

# 2 Вызов метода items() может вернуть все примитивы в сцене, а тип возвращаемого значения - список. 
#   Возвращенные элементы сортируются по убыванию по умолчанию (Qt.DescendingOrder), 
#   то есть располагаются сверху вниз (QPixmapItem, QEllipseItem, QRectItem). 
#   Вы можете изменить значение параметра order, чтобы расположить элементы, возвращенные в списке,
#   в порядке возрастания.
    
        # print(self.scene.items())
        s = "\n\t\t".join([str(i) for i in self.scene.items()])
        print(f'\n scene.items -> {s}')
        # Это перечисление описывает, как элементы в виджете сортируются.
        # print(self.scene.items(order=Qt.AscendingOrder))
        s = "\n\t\t".join([str(i) for i in self.scene.items(order=Qt.AscendingOrder)])
        print(f'\n scene.items(order) -> {s}')
#   itemsBoundingRect() возвращает границы всех примитивов.        
        print(f'\n scene.itemsBoundingRect -> {self.scene.itemsBoundingRect()}')
#   itemAt() может возвращать примитивы в указанной позиции. 
#   Если в этой позиции есть два перекрывающихся примитива, то возвращается верхний примитив. 
#   Переданный QTransform() связан со свойством Flag ItemIgnoresTransformations. 
#   Так как это свойство здесь не установлено, мы можем напрямую передать QTransform()
#   (здесь это не детализировано, в противном случае это может сбить с толку,
#   вы можете сначала просто запомнить его, а потом углубиться в него);
        print(f'\n scene.itemAt -> {self.scene.itemAt(110, 40, QTransform())}')
        print(f' scene.itemAt -> {self.scene.itemAt(110, 90, QTransform())}')
        print(f' scene.itemAt -> {self.scene.itemAt(110, 140, QTransform())}')
        print(f' scene.itemAt -> {self.scene.itemAt(10, 90, QTransform())}')

# 3 Сцена имеет сигнал focusItemChanged. Этот сигнал будет излучаться, 
#   когда мы выбираем разные объекты, при условии, что для объекта установлено свойство ItemIsFocusable.
#   Этот сигнал может принимать два значения: 
#       первое (new_item) - это вновь выбранный примитив, 
#       второе (old_item) - ранее выбранный примитив;

        self.scene.focusItemChanged.connect(self.my_slot)

    def my_slot(self, new_item, old_item):
        print('\n new item: {}\n old item: {}'.format(new_item, old_item))

# 4. Вызовите collidingItems() сцены, чтобы распечатать все другие объекты, 
#    которые сталкиваются с целевым объектом при указанном условии запуска столкновения;

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print(self.scene.collidingItems(self.ellipse, Qt.IntersectsItemShape))
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

# 5 Также необходимо изменить !!!
#   Мы можем дважды щелкнуть на примитиве, чтобы удалить его, вызвав метод removeItem(). 
#   Обратите внимание, что фактически неточно передавать event.pos() напрямую в itemAt(), 
#   потому что event.pos() - это фактически координаты мыши в представлении, а не координаты сцены. 
#   Вы можете увеличить окно и снова дважды щелкнуть, чтобы обнаружить, что примитивы не исчезнут, 
#   потому что размер вида больше не соответствует размеру сцены, а координаты изменились. 
#   Конкретные решения см. В разделе 34.4. (ниже) !!!

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        item = self.scene.itemAt(event.pos(), QTransform())
        self.scene.removeItem(item)
        super().mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ball.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]